# Put a text in front of every new line that a program prints to stdout

Tags: bash, date

So I want to do some logging and therefor, want to put a date in front of a bash script's output. The problem is that is has multiple lines of output. I am able to only put the date before the whole output. But then I have a line without a date in the logs. Of course I can assume the date from the line above is the same, but I was hoping there is a solution.
Thanks in advance!

This is my script that calls another script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $(date "+%F %T") : starting script
echo $(date "+%F %T") : $(./script.sh)
echo $(date "+%F %T") :script ended
```

This is the output:

```
2012-07-26 15:34:12 : starting script
2012-07-26 15:35:14 : First line of output
second line of output
2012-07-26 15:35:17 : script ended
```

And thats what I would like to have:

```
2012-07-26 15:34:12 : starting script
2012-07-26 15:35:14 : First line of output
2012-07-26 15:35:15 : second line of output
2012-07-26 15:35:17 : script ended
```

Comment: I don't suppose you could just just change the second script?

Comment: Nah, Unfortunately not. That's why I came here.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-lines-of-text Also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1508098/259953

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to a [similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-lines-of-text), there are 2 great options.

### awk ([Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-lines-of-text))

```
<command> | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }'
```

### annotate ([Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21909/259953))

[annotate](http://jeroen.a-eskwadraat.nl/sw/annotate/annotate) is a small bash script, that can either be directly obtained through the link provided here, or, on Debian based systems, through the package `devscripts` (in the form of `annotate-output`).

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can use awk for this:

```
./script.sh | awk '{ print strftime()" : "$0; }'
```

(see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html for formatting the date returned by strftime())

Comment: `awk: calling undefined function strftime` -- is this specific to `gawk`?

Comment: Now that you mention it, yes it seems to be :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk`

```
./script.sh | awk '{ print d,$1}' "d=$(date "+%F %T")"
```

`awk` takes an input stream and modifies it's output.  This script is saying "print  d followed by the original output", then then populates `d` with the date.

Comment: Doesn't this evaluate the `date` expression only once as well, so that all such lines print the same time?

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes it does - I had assumed it was picking up the date each time but just finished my test quickly enough

Answer (score 1):

This will print the current date and time before each line of output of `./script.sh`:

```
set -f
./script.sh | while read -r LINE; do echo $(date "+%F %T") : "$LINE"; done
set +f
```

#### How it works

- `set -f` turns off bash expansion (or `echo *` wouldn't print an actual asterisk).
- `while read -r LINE; do ... done` saves one line of output in the variable `$LINE` and executes `...`, until all lines are processed.
- echo $(date "+%F %T") : "$LINE" prints the line with the current time and date.
- `set +f` turns bash expansion back on, so it won't interfere with the rest of your bash script.

Comment: It gets evaluated only once, so every `sed` inserts the same date, from just before starting the second script. Likely not what the user wants...

Comment: I don't think this attempt will work either. AFAIK, the whole subshell gets evaluated completely first, *then* the loop is traversed. So now the times are from *after* the execution.

Comment: Your example doesn't work, since you only delay output, not execution of `ls`. Just try your script with the following `script.sh`: `#!/bin/bash` (newline) `echo 1 ; sleep 1 ; echo 2 ; sleep 2 ; echo 3 ; sleep 3 ; echo 4`

Comment: Use `read` with a `while` loop instead of a for loop.

Comment: @chepner: Good idea.

Comment: @tzippy: There's still one potential problem. If the output contains NULL characters, it won't work properly.

Comment: Is the EOF necessary? Wouldn't `while read -r LINE; do ...; done` be sufficient, or am I missing a special case?

Comment: @chepner: I was only thinking about checking `$LINE`, not `read`'s return value. Man, this answer's revision history is a mess...